# Loop over numbered files and append on every line of file the content of another file with the same number

Tags: shell, text-processing, replace

I have a lot of numbered *.csv files with different numbers of lines and just as many *.txt files. I want to append on every line of file 1.csv the content of file 1.txt, on every line of file 2.csv the content of file 2.txt and so on. Each *.txt file contains only one line.

What I have tried:

```
for i in {1..2}; do for j in {1..2}; do perl -i -p -e "s/^(.+?)$/\1<content of $j.txt>/g" ./$i.csv; done; done
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

example (initial situation):

```
1.csv
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3

2.csv
  line 1
  line 2

1.txt
  yyy

2.txt
  zzz
```

result (should be):

```
1.csv
  line 1yyy
  line 2yyy
  line 3yyy

2.csv
  line 1zzz
  line 2zzz

1.txt
  yyy

2.txt
  zzz
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on your perl attempt, perhaps

```
for f in ./*.csv; do 
  perl -i -lpe 'BEGIN{$x = shift @ARGV} s/$/$x/' "$(<"${f%.csv}.txt")" "$f"
done
```

(assuming ksh/zsh/bash for the `$(<file)` operator; replace with `$(cat<file)` if your shell doesn't support it).

giving

```
$ head ./*.csv
==> ./1.csv <==
  line 1yyy
  line 2yyy
  line 3yyy

==> ./2.csv <==
  line 1zzz
  line 2zzz
```

However you don't really need a regex substitution for this - you could consider replacing `s/$/$x/` by a simple string concatenation `$_ .= $x`

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    awk '
        FNR==NR{txt=$0}
        FNR!=NR{printf "%s%s\n",$0,txt}
    ' "${f%.*}.txt" "$f" > "$f.csv.tmp" && mv "$f.csv.tmp" "$f"
done
```

Output:

```
$ cat a.csv
line 1yyy
line 2yyy
line 3yyy
```

Some modern implementations of `awk` have `-i inplace` option, so you won't need the "tmp and `mv` part". [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk).

Answer (score 0):

A `sed`-oneliner:

```
for i in 1 2 ; do sed -i "s/$/$(cat $i.txt)/" $i.csv ; done
```

`s/$/` I'm replacing the end of each line, thus appending to the line

`$(cat $i.txt)` append the text-file named after the current number.

*Note that this will will lead to problems if the `filen.txt` contains special characters like slash, backslash, quotes, ...*

*If this is a concern, use an [ascii record separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) instead of the `/` in the sed-statement.  You can type those in vim by pressing Ctrl+V, then enter their decimal value --- 030 in this case*